# Dependency ApexTrigger

Tags: apex, trigger, metadata, tooling-api

How can I get all objects (with different actions) related to an `ApexTrigger`?

For example: 
TriggerX ---> Related Objects : Account (insert), CustomObject__c (update) ...

So far, I've tested `"SymbolTable"`, but it only works with `ApexClass`, `ApexClassMember`, and `ApexTriggerMember`.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? Can you be more specific about what you want to do, what you tried, and where you are stuck?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications. Do not put them in the comments on answers, nor even in comments on your own question.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, there's currently no publicly documented way to get at this information. The Developer Console has a way to see this information, but it uses an internal API found at `_ui/common/apex/debug/ApexCSIPage`, which passes in the form values `action=RELATED&extent=TRIGGERS&relatedEntityEnumOrId=<trigger-id>`, and gets back a list of related entities (classes and objects), which is used to show the list of related items. Hopefully, at some point, we'll get a public API that provides this information for us, but for now, you'd have to parse the code yourself, which may not be very doable in Visualforce.

Comment: I have seen Illuminated Cloud IDE generate offline symbol table. http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/. Don't know how it works. But can be used to generate dependencies list.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal They do it via an internal compiler, if I remember correctly. BrainEngine (now defunct) actually had a virtual Apex Runtime engine that could simulate salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

You can not simply grab this information by querying any object. But you can use simple Query OR (tooling api) to grab the Body of trigger and traverse through the body with your logic (some of them given below) to parse the objects name..

1. Like hard-coded name of Standard object...as Account
2. Custom object name is always ends with __c
3. For loop always iterates on either object or any wrapper class..
4. new operator is always used to instantiate either object or wrapper class...

May be you can build logic better than me...

Here is simple SOQL to get that:

```
SELECT Body FROM ApexTrigger where id=''
```

Here is tolling API poc:
[image]

Here is the sample code to make Tooling api call:

```
HttpRequest requestinside = new HttpRequest();
requestinside.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
requestinside.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
requestinside.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexTrigger/01q90000000wteL');

Http http = new Http ();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(requestinside);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

Comment: Wz can get trigger's body without using Tooling API, just a SOQL : 
`SELECT Body FROM ApexTrigger`

Comment: You are right...let me update the answer...

Answer (score -1):

Please go through the below trailhead module to understand the Apex Trigger:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_triggers

Here are the best practices that you should follow while writing your Apex Trigger:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

I am not 100% sure about how to fetch related objects from Trigger Context, but this is something you can try -

- Call [listMetadata()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listmetadata.htm) with type "CustomObject"
- Remove all types that have "__c" suffix from resulting list of object types
- Call [retrieve()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve.htm) with "[RetrieveRequest.specificFiles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve_request.htm)" parameter with list from Step 2.

Comment: I already know how to write a trigger. 
My question is : How to get a list of objects related to trigger using Tooling API or Metadata API ? (Like SymbolTable)

Comment: Put some comments. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: I believe you are trying to build an IDE or tools using tooling API?

Comment: No. Just a Visualforce Page that shows every trigger's dependancy.

Comment: I genuinly doubt there is something available that will help you to list the metadata dependency for trigger. Had it been custom field or class it would be easy as trying to delete it will list all the dependent places.